# how calculation be done in JSON object elements

Tags: django

I have declared `instalment_2` as `JSONField` in the Django model.

My concern here is I am getting below error:

> string indices must be integers

I tried all the ways which were available on the internet. But no luck.

I am passing this JSON as POST request:

```
"instalment_2": {
    "type": "instalment_2",
    "mode": "cash",
    "date": "1/09/2019",
    "amount": "35000"
}
```

It should calculate `paid` and `balance` based on installment amounts. `instalment_1` amount is already in the table.

Now I am trying to do below.

```
instalment_2 = {
    "type": body['instalment_2']['type'],
    "mode": body['instalment_2']['mode'],
    "date": body['instalment_2']['date'],
    "amount": body['instalment_2']['amount']
}

paid = int(obj.instalment_1['amount']) + int(obj.instalment_2['amount'])

balance = int(obj.total) - paid
```

Comment: Your original "JSON" as you show it here is invalid JSON. JSON must always start with a `{` or `[`. It can't start with `"instalment_2"`. Please show your exact `body` and the full JSON. If this is really the string you're posting, then you'll have to parse it as string first to extract the dictionary.

Comment: You're probably right. I've withheld my answer. Need more info on the error.

Comment: body {"instalment_2": {
    "type": "instalment_2",
    "mode": "cash",
    "date": "1/09/2019",
    "amount": "35000"
} }

Comment: instalment_1 record already stored in DB as

Comment: "instalment_1": {
    "type": "instalment_1",
    "mode": "cash",
    "date": "1/09/2019",
    "amount": "45000"
}

Comment: initial my paid and balance is " " . now i have to calculate paid and balance as per below statements

Comment: paid = int(obj.instalment_1['amount']) + int(obj.instalment_2['amount'])

Comment: balance = int(obj.total) - paid

Comment: i am getting error sting indices must be integers

Comment: please suggest me to do further .

Comment: body_unicode=request.body.decode('utf-8')
  details=[]
  body=json.loads(body_unicode)
  student=body['student']
  if(Fees.objects.filter(student=student).values('pk').exists()):
    obj=Fees.objects.get(student=student)
    if "instalment_2" in body:
      if(obj.instalment_2==''):
        instalment_2={"type":body['instalment_2']['type'],"mode":body['instalment_2']['mode'],"date":body['instalment_2']['date'],"amount":body['instalment_2']['amount']}

Comment: paid=int(obj.instalment_1['amount'])+int(obj.instalment_2['amount'])
        balance=int(obj.total)-paid
        Fees.objects.filter(student=student).update(paid=paid,balance=balance,instalment_2=instalment_2)

Comment: @RoopaSejekan Please copy the full error message and paste it here in your question.

Comment: string indices must be integers
Exception Location: /home/bitjini/Documents/openmindsworld/add_fees/views.py in get_queryset, line 109